# Is it appropriate to write the summary of an online course on my website?

Tags: plagiarism

I am doing a few courses on Coursera and youtube, while watching the lectures I usually take some notes, adding extra explanations and examples on things that I found difficult to understand. Now, I am thinking that I can clean them up a little and post them on my website, but I don't know if that would be considered plagiarism or otherwise inappropriate.

If I do post anything I will properly cite the course I am referring to and not post any quiz/assignment questions or answers, but also I won't really be adding any original work of my own, just a condensed summary and maybe some additional examples that I found useful from other sources.

Would something like that be a good idea?

Comment: Is your question more about "aiding" the plagiarism of others rather than plagiarism on your part?

Comment: I think the question would be more about potential copyright issues rather than plagiarism. If you are transcribing complete lectures, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have appropriately cited the original sources, it is not plagiarism. You are allowed to write about topics that others have already written about.

This seems like a fine idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting something very similar to the original content (e.g. summary notes they provide you) is probably where you want to draw the line. If you are adding your own notes/content/work, including effort to further clarify or distill information, I don't see an ethical problem. Worst case, your blog is so popular they request you remove the content.